# attempt to connect to a remote server failed inet: Local Computer:0

Tags: macos, error-handling, statistics, spss

I installed SPSS version 25 on my macOS Catalina. When starting the program the following error comes up "attempt to connect to a remote server failed inet: Local Computer:0"

I've no idea how to solve this, I already turned of my firewall but it's not working. The crazy thing is that yesterday night it was working, but now the next day it is not.

Any help would be super appreciated!!

Edit: I read all the other forums online about this, but I can't get if fixed...

Answer (score 0):

macOS 10.15 (Catalina) introduced new security features.  As IBM SPSS Statisticxs was already in the field prior to Catalina's release, there were issues.

Please see here:
https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/2019/10/08/spss-statistics-on-catalina-macos-10-15/?_ga=2.257881487.541667164.1604327861-699861288.1590164240

Comment: Please try to include some summary of external links so that if/when the external link changes, we still have the answer preserved here.